# Force download pdf in Joomla 3.0

Tags: pdf, joomla, download

Im trying to make it to where on my Joomla site, whenever someone clicks a link for a PDF that instead of opening in a new tab or window it automatically opens the save dialog box. I have seen solutions for this online but I dont know where to edit and put the code in.

Anyone know where the code is to edit?

Here is the link for the solution I found, I just dont know what file to place it all in.

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2553338

Comment: Where is your PDF file? Is it just one file or more? Are you using any component to manange this file? Imho you need to change the PDF header when it's called (usually by PHP).

Comment: changing the header is the solution ive found but I dont know where to find it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you use a document management system for something like this. [DOCman](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads/10958) is probably the most widely used solution for something  like this.

Comment: There's a good chance that you'll find what you need at http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads

Comment: Dunno why this anwer got upvoted, since its totally dumb. For a simple thing like just wanting to download a PDF, a subfolder for downloads is the right solution with a single htaccess-file as Kennysteve stated. Another extension for that reason is just a security problem and opens even more gates for potential hackers.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line to your .htaccess file and ensure to save it

**AddType application/octet-stream .pdf**